# Multiple editableTable in a CP page

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, form, table

Is it already built-in in CraftCMS to make multiple editableTable in a CP page? The behaviour would be similar to Matrix field where you add a matrix block, the matrix block appears. What I want is that instead of the matrix block, editableTable appears. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a plugin called Table Maker. I've never tried it but it looks like it lets your users create tables in the cp.

[Table Maker](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/table-maker/features)

Comment: Thanks @AbbeyDesign. I'll check out Table Maker plugin. I was thinking more on multiple tables in a single CP page.

Comment: You can have multiple table fields without a plugin.

Comment: Yes I wouldn't use any plugin for creating the tables. I guess I wasn't clear with my question. My editableTable tables would be dynamic. There's an add button and when pressed, it will add the table much like the matrix block behaviour.

Comment: Craft has a table field out of the box. So you could have one or multiple on a page. Per matrix block behavior, I don't follow, but you could have a matrix field with a table block and the user could add a table by clicking a button.